# Split a large winform class

Tags: c#, class, coding-style

I'm using WinForms to design an application. It has many controls (buttons, menus, etc) that have underlying event handlers. I find that my class is getting rather large and hard for one person to navigate. This is due to the fact that each control requires one or more methods to handle events within the context of the window.

What are some techniques for organizing these methods or splitting up such a large class?

Comment: Already using #region? It's nice having all non-designer code in one class, no room for surprises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is just about navigation you can [split your class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in several files, just add the `partial` before the class declaration in every file.

Generally if you have some very complex controls or event handlers bound to these controls it can be reasonable to separate those in your own custom user controls and just add them to your form. Just add a new user control element to your project and customize it the way you need.

All your controls are immediately available as any other .Net controls in the same project, but you might also want to put them in a separate DLL file (if you want even more separation of your code).

Here is [a nice tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx) how to design your own controls in WinForms.

Comment: The partial keyword came to mind immediately. I was hoping to find other techniques to compact or group my code into areas. My controls are usually fairly simple, it's just that there are a lot of them and each one has an event handler.

Comment: If you can bundle your logic into meaningful commands you can implement something like Command design pattern (similar how it is done in WPF -- look for ICommand interface) and just invoke those with necessary context and parameters from your code-behind in the form.